# integerValue is undeclared

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm trying to make buble sort in Obj-C and found some trouble here:

```
for (b=size-1;b<=a;--b){
        NSNumber *num;
        num=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:99999];
        NSLog(@"%i",num.integerValue);
        if ([array objectAtIndex:[integerValue b]==num.integerValue){
            //if ([array objectAtIndex:b] <[array objectAtIndex:b-1]) {
            NSLog(@"ok");}
```

debugger says than integerValue is undeclared.

Comment: Where do you think the problem might be? What have you tried to do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The error is when you are invoking a object named integerValue:

```
[integerValue b]
```

I suppose that you haven't declared any instance of a class with that name.

Answer (score 2):

```
objectAtIndex:[integerValue b]
```

Doesn't make a lot of sense to me. I think you meant

```
objectAtIndex:b
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here

```
if ([array objectAtIndex:[integerValue b]==num.integerValue){
```

What are you trying to do with `[integerValue b]`?...